# Not getting Proper output for check_iostat for nrpe plugins

Tags: nagios, ubuntu-14.04, nrpe, iostat

My iostat is giving following output

```
$ iostat 
Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (Inksedge)  08/13/2015  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap1            0.62         0.13         9.01    3282841  226020852
xvdb              0.03         0.00         0.12       7721    2999916
xvdc              0.00         0.00         0.00       1376          0
```

check_iostat is not working for device xvdap1 ! I tried for xvda, xvda1 also but no use !

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_iostat -d xvda1 -w 100,100,100 -c 200,200,200
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
OK - I/O stats tps= MB_read/s= MB_written/s= | 'tps'=; 'MB_read/s'=; 'MB_written/s'=;
```

So what should i give device name to get proper output  ?

It is working for xvdb :

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_iostat -d xvdb -w 100,100,100 -c 200,200,200
OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 | 'tps'=0.00; 'MB_read/s'=0.00; 'MB_written/s'=0.00;
```

Comment: Got the answer : As iostat command was missing it gave wrong output ! 

 # apt-get install sysstat

Got output on Nagios after installing sysstat :

    IO-Stats /dev/xvda

    OK 08-19-2015 14:28:10 43d 8h 7m 28s 1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=2.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 
    IO-Stats /dev/xvdb
    OK 08-19-2015 14:26:48 61d 4h 47m 46s 1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 
    IO-Stats /dev/xvdc
    OK 08-19-2015 14:26:48 61d 4h 47m 13s 1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer : As iostat command was missing it gave wrong output !

# apt-get install sysstat

Got output on Nagios after installing sysstat :

```
IO-Stats /dev/xvda

OK  08-19-2015 14:28:10 43d 8h 7m 28s   1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=2.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 
IO-Stats /dev/xvdb
OK  08-19-2015 14:26:48 61d 4h 47m 46s  1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 
IO-Stats /dev/xvdc
OK  08-19-2015 14:26:48 61d 4h 47m 13s  1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00 
IO-Stats /dev/xvdf
OK  08-19-2015 14:25:10 6d 3h 4m 19s    1/4 OK - I/O stats tps=0.00 MB_read/s=0.00 MB_written/s=0.00
```